# Cadance Error, PCB desining

Tags: pcb, drc

I am trying to design a simple PCB, using Cadance 17.02 , after importing schematic to PCB designer all footprint pin have DRC Error. the Error is :
"Thru pin to shape spacing" with  both actual and Require value of zero.
How can I correct the Er?

Comment: Setup your constraints, in constraint manager.

Comment: I know it s constain manager setting, but I dont know which field I should re-assign :(

Comment: If you mouse over the DRC Error, and right click, there is an option to show in Constraint Manager.